# Schengen visa to meet my girlfriend in Denmark

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel, denmark

I met my girlfriend over internet and we wanted to meet and celebrate Christmas and new year's together. She's from Denmark. So her dad agreed for me to stay at their place and sent me a vu2 invitation form. But they've clearly mentioned on their website that "In order for a boy/girlfriend (including applicants seeking to travel to Denmark to marry) to qualify for a visa, the applicant and the individual living in Denmark must prove that they have had and still have a long-term relationship. This involves: proving that both host and applicant are unmarried or divorced, that they have met in person and have been together within the past year. If the relationship only involves telephone, written or online communication, a visa will not be granted."

Please help me out with the following:

1. How do I establish my relationship with them.

Do I tell them that our parents are close friends and they wanted to come over for Christmas (this is something that I came up with)?

2. They made a small error in the invitation form: they've included my surname along with my first name in the first name column.

First name: my full surname + Sid
Last name : my last name

Will this be an issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to go meet her instead .

Comment: Please split this into two separate questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Do not lie.** If you are caught your credibility for future applications will be damaged.

**Ask her to visit you instead.** Or meet in a holiday destination where both of you can travel. If you do that and document your meetings, you will have an established relationship.

If you are serious about your relationship, that should be a small obstacle.

---

To get a tourist visa, you have to convince the visa officials that you **are a tourist**.

- You have to show good reasons why you will leave again and not overstay. A stable and well-paid job would help, but that is unlikely at your age. A stable and *not finished* course of education might help.
- You will have to explain how you plan to pay for the visit. Many 19 year olds are rich enough to afford the trip, most are not. So the motivations of the people who fund your trip come into question.

Comment: Even this standard advice may not suffice in the OP's situation. The rules the OP has run into are intended to guard against daughters in immigrant families being pressured into arranged marriages with men from the old country. Considerable bureaucratic ingenuity is invested in preventing such suitors from gaining entry to meet the (putative) victims, so even though by the Schengen rules it _should_ be enough to demonstrate genuine intent to leave after _this_ visit, the consulate will probably be very reluctant to be convinced of that.

Comment: ... especially since the OPs situation has several points of similarity with the usual arranged-relationship scare story (which is something that semi-regularly fuels moral panics in the Danish press): The couple have never met in person, they're contemplating a very long initial visit -- and most of all, the girl's parents are curiously willing to bankroll it all. Most parents of late-teen girls would have a lot of reservations towards turning an internet fling with someone neither of them have met into a 45-day staying guest. What if they _don't_ hit off?

Comment: Or you can meet in a third country, as holidays for both. But for what I see from other comments, it seems that nobody want to make sacrifices, so also the commitment is low.

Comment: @HenningMakholm her parents know me well.  we've interacted a lot of times . And also were in a serious relationship and my dad's paying for the trip

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  they're letting me stay at their place for 45 days and we came up with a plan of meeting in her country